# Display or hide some divs when an input is filled. display an alert if two input have the same value, and erase the last input

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I'm trying to display or hide some div depending on what will be the text filled in the input.

so actualy I have done this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkdiv()
    {
    var position1= document.getElementById("position1").value;
        if(position1==1)
        {
         document.getElementById("a1").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
        }
        else
        {
         document.getElementById("a1").style.visibility= "visible"                        
        }
        if(position1=="2")
        {
         document.getElementById("a2").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
        }
        if(position1!="2")
        {
         document.getElementById("a2").style.visibility= "visible"                        
        }
        if(position1=="3")
        {
         document.getElementById("a3").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
        }
        if(position1!="3")
        {
         document.getElementById("a3").style.visibility= "visible"                        
        }
         if(position1=="4")
        {
         document.getElementById("a4").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
        }
        if(position1!="4")
        {
         document.getElementById("a4").style.visibility= "visible"                        
        }  
         if(position1=="5")
        {
         document.getElementById("a5").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
        }
        if(position1!="5")
        {
         document.getElementById("a5").style.visibility= "visible"                        
        }
        if(position1=="6")
        {
         document.getElementById("a6").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
        }
        if(position1!="6")
        {
         document.getElementById("a6").style.visibility= "visible"                        
        }
         if(position1=="7")
        {
         document.getElementById("a7").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
        }
        if(position1!="7")
        {
         document.getElementById("a7").style.visibility= "visible"                        
        }
         if(position1=="8")
        {
         document.getElementById("a8").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
        }
        if(position1!="8")
        {
         document.getElementById("a8").style.visibility= "visible"                        
        }          
        if(position1=="9")
        {
         document.getElementById("a9").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
        }
        if(position1!="9")
        {
         document.getElementById("a9").style.visibility= "visible"                        
        }
         if(position1=="10")
        {
         document.getElementById("a10").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
        }
        if(position1!="10")
        {
         document.getElementById("a10").style.visibility= "visible"                        
        }          
        if(position1=="11")
        {
         document.getElementById("a11").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
        }
        if(position1!="11")
        {
         document.getElementById("a11").style.visibility= "visible"                        
        }   
        if(position1=="12")
        {
         document.getElementById("a12").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
        }
        if(position1!="12")
        {
         document.getElementById("a12").style.visibility= "visible"                        
        } 


    }
       checkdiv();  
  </script>
```

And all of this past with the column Ordre of the following table:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<table width='100%' id='boxa' align='center' ><thead><tr><th scope='col' width='3%'><strong>CODE CLIENT</strong></th><th scope='col' width='10%'><strong>TITRE</strong></th><th scope='col' width='15%'><strong>POSTE</strong></th><th scope='col' width='3%'><strong>ORDRE</strong></th><th scope='col' width='25%'><strong>DESCRIPTION</strong></th><th scope='col' width='10%'><strong>VU CLIENT</strong></th><th scope='col' width='10%'><strong>VU TIERS</strong></th></tr></thead><tbody> <tr>

        <td>
        <input name="data[1][code_client]" type="text"  id="code_client1" size="5"  onkeyup="clientventilation()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[1][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle1" onkeyup="titreventilation()"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[1][poste]" type="text" value="Principal" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[1][ordre]" id="position1" type="text" size="2"  onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[1][description]" type="text" value="Montant de la dette" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[1][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[1][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[2][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client2"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[2][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle2"   /></td>
        <td><input name="data[2][poste]" type="text" value="Int&eacute;r&ecirc;ts" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[2][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position2" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[2][description]" type="text" value="Int&eacute;r&ecirc;ts (sur soldes des factures d&ucirc;es)" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[2][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[2][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[3][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client3"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[3][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle3"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[3][poste]" type="text" value="Clause p&eacute;nale" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[3][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position3" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[3][description]" type="text" value="Clause p&eacute;nale contractuelle" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[3][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[3][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[4][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client4"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[4][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle4"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[4][poste]" type="text" value="Dommages et Int&eacute;r&ecirc;ts" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[4][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position4" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[4][description]" type="text" value="Montant des Dommages et Int&eacute;r&ecirc;ts" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[4][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[4][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[5][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client5"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[5][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle5"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[5][poste]" type="text" value="Article 700 du CPC" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[5][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position5" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[5][description]" type="text" value="Montant correspondant &agrave; la condamnation" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[5][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[5][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[6][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client6"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[6][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle6"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[6][poste]" type="text" value="Frais AR" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[6][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position6" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[6][description]" type="text" value="Montant des frais d'accus&eacute;s r&eacute;ception et de courriers" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[6][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[6][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[7][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client7"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[7][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle7"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[7][poste]" type="text" value="Art. 441-6 CC" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[7][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position7" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[7][description]" type="text" value="Article 441-6 du code du commerce" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[7][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[7][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[8][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client8"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[8][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle8"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[8][poste]" type="text" value="Frais et Agios" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[8][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position8" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[8][description]" type="text" value="Montant des frais &amp; agios bancaires" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[8][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[8][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[9][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client9"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[9][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle9"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[9][poste]" type="text" value="D&eacute;pens" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[9][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position9" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[9][description]" type="text" value="Total calcul&eacute;" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[9][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[9][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[10][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client10"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[10][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle10"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[10][poste]" type="text" value="Article 475-1-CPP" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[10][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position10" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[10][description]" type="text" value="Article 475-1 Du code de Proc&eacute;dure p&eacute;nale" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[10][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[10][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[11][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client11"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[11][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle11"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[11][poste]" type="text" value="Frais d'ex&eacute;cution" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[11][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position11" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[11][description]" type="text" value="Montant des frais d'ex&eacute;cution" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[11][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[11][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
                <td><input name="data[12][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client12"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[12][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle12"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[12][poste]" type="text" value="Contribution &agrave; l'aide juridiqu" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[12][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position12" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[12][description]" type="text" value="Contribution Ã  l'aide juridique" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[12][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[12][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[13][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client13"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[13][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle13"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[13][poste]" type="text" value="Frais de greffe" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[13][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position13" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[13][description]" type="text" value="Montant des frais de greffe" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[13][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[13][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

But when I try to make the function work it says to me can not read the property style of null.  I would like just to hide the orange box with the number if the number is put into the input of the column "ordre". And if somebody write twice the same number as it exist in an other box just to display an alert. I really lost because this beggining does not work.

Any advice or help will be much appreciated

Here is the jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/uXcQh/

Comment: Please, please tell me you didn't write all of those 350 `if` conditions by hand. Consider using a JS library like jQuery. If properly used, it will simplify your code immensely.

Comment: yes consider using jquery or other .

Comment: `document.getElementById()` returns `null` if no element is found with the `id` you provide, and the html you show doesn't have any elements with the ids from your function, so all of your `getElementById()` calls return `null` and you can't set `style` properties of `null`. (Sorry, I can't check your fiddle, it won't load for me.)

Comment: Also, you're missing so much ";" in you JS...

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eeSFD/) id a simple example on how to show and hide objects according to `class`

Comment: No I wrote it myself much time using Copy/Paste, because I' just started using javascript and for the beginning it is not verry easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are including you JavaScript in your head tags, that might be the cause because the DOM is not fully loaded when the function is called.

```
<html>
   <head>
       <script></script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

My suggestion is to do this instead.

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
       All your html goes here.
       FINALLY.
       <script></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is the code that works for me

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
<table width='100%' id='boxa' align='center' ><thead><tr><th scope='col' width='3%'><strong>CODE CLIENT</strong></th><th scope='col' width='10%'><strong>TITRE</strong></th><th scope='col' width='15%'><strong>POSTE</strong></th><th scope='col' width='3%'><strong>ORDRE</strong></th><th scope='col' width='25%'><strong>DESCRIPTION</strong></th><th scope='col' width='10%'><strong>VU CLIENT</strong></th><th scope='col' width='10%'><strong>VU TIERS</strong></th></tr></thead><tbody>    <tr>

        <td>
        <input name="data[1][code_client]" type="text"  id="code_client1" size="5"  onkeyup="clientventilation()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[1][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle1" onkeyup="titreventilation()"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[1][poste]" type="text" value="Principal" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[1][ordre]" id="position1" type="text" size="2"  onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[1][description]" type="text" value="Montant de la dette" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[1][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[1][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[2][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client2"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[2][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle2"   /></td>
        <td><input name="data[2][poste]" type="text" value="Int&eacute;r&ecirc;ts" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[2][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position2" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[2][description]" type="text" value="Int&eacute;r&ecirc;ts (sur soldes des factures d&ucirc;es)" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[2][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[2][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[3][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client3"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[3][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle3"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[3][poste]" type="text" value="Clause p&eacute;nale" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[3][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position3" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[3][description]" type="text" value="Clause p&eacute;nale contractuelle" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[3][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[3][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[4][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client4"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[4][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle4"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[4][poste]" type="text" value="Dommages et Int&eacute;r&ecirc;ts" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[4][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position4" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[4][description]" type="text" value="Montant des Dommages et Int&eacute;r&ecirc;ts" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[4][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[4][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[5][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client5"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[5][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle5"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[5][poste]" type="text" value="Article 700 du CPC" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[5][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position5" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[5][description]" type="text" value="Montant correspondant &agrave; la condamnation" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[5][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[5][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[6][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client6"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[6][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle6"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[6][poste]" type="text" value="Frais AR" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[6][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position6" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[6][description]" type="text" value="Montant des frais d'accus&eacute;s r&eacute;ception et de courriers" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[6][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[6][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[7][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client7"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[7][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle7"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[7][poste]" type="text" value="Art. 441-6 CC" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[7][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position7" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[7][description]" type="text" value="Article 441-6 du code du commerce" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[7][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[7][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[8][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client8"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[8][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle8"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[8][poste]" type="text" value="Frais et Agios" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[8][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position8" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[8][description]" type="text" value="Montant des frais &amp; agios bancaires" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[8][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[8][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[9][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client9"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[9][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle9"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[9][poste]" type="text" value="D&eacute;pens" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[9][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position9" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[9][description]" type="text" value="Total calcul&eacute;" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[9][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[9][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[10][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client10"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[10][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle10"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[10][poste]" type="text" value="Article 475-1-CPP" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[10][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position10" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[10][description]" type="text" value="Article 475-1 Du code de Proc&eacute;dure p&eacute;nale" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[10][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[10][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[11][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client11"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[11][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle11"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[11][poste]" type="text" value="Frais d'ex&eacute;cution" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[11][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position11" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[11][description]" type="text" value="Montant des frais d'ex&eacute;cution" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[11][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[11][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
                <td><input name="data[12][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client12"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[12][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle12"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[12][poste]" type="text" value="Contribution &agrave; l'aide juridiqu" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[12][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position12" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[12][description]" type="text" value="Contribution Ã  l'aide juridique" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[12][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[12][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><input name="data[13][code_client]" type="text" size="5" id="code_client13"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[13][libelle]" type="text" size="10" id="libelle13"  /></td>
        <td><input name="data[13][poste]" type="text" value="Frais de greffe" size="30" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[13][ordre]" type="text" size="2" id="position13" onblur="checkdiv()" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[13][description]" type="text" value="Montant des frais de greffe" size="40" /></td><td><select name="data[13][vu_client]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td><td><select name="data[13][vu_tiers]" ><option value="oui">oui</option><option value="non">non</option></select></td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th scope="col"><div id="a1" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; border: 5px solid rgb(255, 127, 80); text-align: center; visibility: visible; "><font color="coral" size="+3"><strong>1</strong></font></div></th>
    <th scope="col"><div id="a2" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; border: 5px solid rgb(255, 127, 80); text-align: center; visibility: visible; "><font color="coral" size="+3"><strong>2</strong></font></div></th>
    <th scope="col"><div id="a3" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; border: 5px solid rgb(255, 127, 80); text-align: center; visibility: visible; "><font color="coral" size="+3"><strong>3</strong></font></div></th>
    <th scope="col"><div id="a4" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; border: 5px solid rgb(255, 127, 80); text-align: center; visibility: visible; "><font color="coral" size="+3"><strong>4</strong></font></div></th>
    <th scope="col"><div id="a5" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; border: 5px solid rgb(255, 127, 80); text-align: center; visibility: visible; "><font color="coral" size="+3"><strong>5</strong></font></div></th>
    <th scope="col"><div id="a6" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; border: 5px solid rgb(255, 127, 80); text-align: center; visibility: visible; "><font color="coral" size="+3"><strong>6</strong></font></div></th>
    <th scope="col"><div id="a7" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; border: 5px solid rgb(255, 127, 80); text-align: center; visibility: visible; "><font color="coral" size="+3"><strong>7</strong></font></div></th>
    <th scope="col"><div id="a8" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; border: 5px solid rgb(255, 127, 80); text-align: center; visibility: visible; "><font color="coral" size="+3"><strong>8</strong></font></div></th>
    <th scope="col"><div id="a9" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; border: 5px solid rgb(255, 127, 80); text-align: center; visibility: visible; "><font color="coral" size="+3"><strong>9</strong></font></div></th>
    <th scope="col"><div id="a10" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; border: 5px solid rgb(255, 127, 80); text-align: center; visibility: visible; "><font color="coral" size="+3"><strong>10</strong></font></div></th>
    <th scope="col"><div id="a11" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; border: 5px solid rgb(255, 127, 80); text-align: center; visibility: visible; "><font color="coral" size="+3"><strong>11</strong></font></div></th>
    <th scope="col"><div id="a12" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; border: 5px solid rgb(255, 127, 80); text-align: center; visibility: visible; "><font color="coral" size="+3"><strong>12</strong></font></div></th>
    <th scope="col"><div id="a13" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; border: 5px solid rgb(255, 127, 80); text-align: center; visibility: hidden; "><font color="coral" size="+3"><strong>13</strong></font></div></th>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
?
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkdiv()
{
    var position1= document.getElementById("position1").value;
    if(position1== 1 )
    {
    alert(document.getElementById("a1"));
        document.getElementById("a1").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
    }
    else
    {
     document.getElementById("a1").style.visibility= "visible"                        
    }
    if(position1=="2")
    {
     document.getElementById("a2").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
    }
    if(position1!="2")
    {
     document.getElementById("a2").style.visibility= "visible"                        
    }
    if(position1=="3")
    {
     document.getElementById("a3").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
    }
    if(position1!="3")
    {
     document.getElementById("a3").style.visibility= "visible"                        
    }
     if(position1=="4")
    {
     document.getElementById("a4").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
    }
    if(position1!="4")
    {
     document.getElementById("a4").style.visibility= "visible"                        
    }  
     if(position1=="5")
    {
     document.getElementById("a5").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
    }
    if(position1!="5")
    {
     document.getElementById("a5").style.visibility= "visible"                        
    }
    if(position1=="6")
    {
     document.getElementById("a6").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
    }
    if(position1!="6")
    {
     document.getElementById("a6").style.visibility= "visible"                        
    }
     if(position1=="7")
    {
     document.getElementById("a7").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
    }
    if(position1!="7")
    {
     document.getElementById("a7").style.visibility= "visible"                        
    }
     if(position1=="8")
    {
     document.getElementById("a8").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
    }
    if(position1!="8")
    {
     document.getElementById("a8").style.visibility= "visible"                        
    }          
    if(position1=="9")
    {
     document.getElementById("a9").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
    }
    if(position1!="9")
    {
     document.getElementById("a9").style.visibility= "visible"                        
    }
     if(position1=="10")
    {
     document.getElementById("a10").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
    }
    if(position1!="10")
    {
     document.getElementById("a10").style.visibility= "visible"                        
    }          
    if(position1=="11")
    {
     document.getElementById("a11").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
    }
    if(position1!="11")
    {
     document.getElementById("a11").style.visibility= "visible"                        
    }   
    if(position1=="12")
    {
     document.getElementById("a12").style.visibility = "hidden"                        
    }
    if(position1!="12")
    {
     document.getElementById("a12").style.visibility= "visible"                        
    }
}  
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, you are missing the divs with the a1,a2,...,an

Comment: can you show me your jsfiddle? cause mine is not working at all

Comment: Ok, I will do the same for the 12 other elements. thank you verry much for your help